# Error creating OKTA sign in: "Your Okta url must start with https"

Tags: reactjs, okta

I receive the error below on creating authentication with OKTA app. I can't work out why this is pulling through as undefined.

Error: Your Okta URL must start with https. Current value: undefined/oauth2/default.

Below is where I call the credentials:

Below is in my .env.local:

```
REACT_APP_OKTA_CLIENT_ID='################'
REACT_APP_OKTA_ORG_URL='https://d#######.okta.com'
```

Below is where I call the credentials:

```
const oktaConfig = {
  issuer: `${process.env.REACT_APP_OKTA_ORG_URL}/oauth2/default`,
  redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}/login/callback`,
  client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_OKTA_CLIENT_ID,
};
```

This is in React using Okta

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had not saved the .env.local file in root, which was why it was undefined. Problem solved - silly error.